# FontAwesomeFX Could not find de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11 with Gradle (IntelliJ)

Tags: gradle, javafx

I modified my `build.gradle` to add dependencies of fontawesomefx but I have always this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11.
```

build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.10'
    implementation "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11"
}
```

Comment: Weird, copy/pasted you implementation line and works fine for me, and downloaded the jar...  I know it's silly but make sure you have mavenCentral() repository set up in your Gradle build file.. also, checking mvnreopsitory.com, I couldn't find that version of the artifact, latest version is  '4.7.0-9.1.2`

Comment: Thank you very much @b3tuning ! it works when I change the version

Answer (score 1):

It works when I changed :

```
implementation "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11"
```

to

```
implementation "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2"
```

As @b3tuning said latest version is '4.7.0-9.1.2` in mvnreopsitory